# Uniqueness of (co)homology theories on category of finite CW pairs

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

By a (co)homology theory on the category of (finite) CW pairs I mean a functor from the category of (finite) CW pairs to the category of graded $R$-modules, satisfying the Eilenberg-Steenrod (co)homology axioms (including the dimension axiom). The existence part of this is done in any standard algebraic topology textbook by showing that the singular (co)homology is a actually a (co)homology theory.

I want to have some reference for the uniqueness part. To be precise, I want to prove the following (and similar results for cohomology theories) :

> $H_\star$ and $\hat{H}_\star$ be two homology theories, $p$ be a point. Then for any homomorphism $H_0(p)\to \hat{H}_0(p)$, there is a natural transformation $H_\star\to\hat{H}_\star$ inducing the given map. If $H_0(p)\to\hat{H}_0(p)$ is given to be an isomorphism, the natural transformation induces isomorphism $H_\star(X,A)\to\hat{H}_\star(X,A)$ for any pair $(X,A)$ i.e $H_\star$ and $\hat{H}_\star$ becomes equivalent.

Can someone please provide me some reference for this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is Theorem 7.55 of Switzer's "Algebraic Topology" (at least in the appropriate formulation, see Qiaochu Yuan's comment).

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. For example, complex K-theory has the same value at a point as 2-periodic integral cohomology, but they are not isomorphic as cohomology theories. I believe there isn't even a map of cohomology theories between them which gives an isomorphism on a point. (There is such a map after rationalization, which is given by the Chern character. But after rationalization both theories become 2-periodic rational cohomology.)

The correct statement (I think; I'm not 100% on this) is only that evaluation at a point is [conservative](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/conservative+functor): that is, given a natural transformation of cohomology theories, if it's an isomorphism on a point then it's an isomorphism. This is a version of the Whitehead theorem, but for [spectra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spectrum) (although it might only be true for connective spectra...).

Comment: I am not sure I get your counter-example, since I am not familiar with K-theory at all. I am actually going through [this](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/davkir.pdf). See page 21 for the statement I want to prove. Maybe I misinterpreted something?

Comment: @ChesterX: oh, so you're including the dimension axiom. You should specify that in the question; I don't think that's a standard convention in modern algebraic topology. Anyway I think this is just a standard cell-by-cell induction sort of deal.

Comment: I thought that without the dimension axiom, it is called an extra-ordinary homology theory. I should have specified that I am talking about ordinary ones. I have edited the question.

Comment: @ChesterX: I think the standard convention in modern algebraic topology is that "(co)homology theory" means "extraordinary (co)homology theory" by default.